# Set pandas row with itterable object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` which rows consists of both scalar values and matrices of different sizes. The matrices as stored with `np.object` datatype. I run into problems however when I try to assign an entire row at the same time. How would I do that.

Here's the reason behind my choice of data structure as requested by MaxU:
I record several parameters (scalar, uint16, int32 & double) of a machine as well as one camera image. There is one blob on the image which however differs in size and position from shot-to-shot. I create a dynamic region of interest which is big enough to capture the blob but saves space with respect to the full image, normally resulting in a 50x100 instead of a 1024x1024 uint16. Furthermore I extract several parameters from that image which are all again scalar values represented in the table. Each row corresponds to one recording of all the parameters.

`mwe` example below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

raw = np.zeros(10, dtype=[('a', 'f8'), ('b', 'i4'), ('c', 'O')])
print(f'raw\n {raw}')
print(f'raw.dtype\n {raw.dtype}\n')

frame = pd.DataFrame(raw)
print(f'frame\n {frame}')
print(f'frame.dtypes\n {frame.dtypes}')

# Works fine
frame.loc[0, ('a', 'b', 'c')] = (1, 2, 'a')

# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
frame.loc[0, ('a', 'b', 'c')] = (1, 2, np.zeros((20, 20)))
```

returns:

```
raw
 [( 0., 0, 0) ( 0., 0, 0) ( 0., 0, 0) ( 0., 0, 0) ( 0., 0, 0) ( 0., 0, 0)
 ( 0., 0, 0) ( 0., 0, 0) ( 0., 0, 0) ( 0., 0, 0)]
raw.dtype
 [('a', '<f8'), ('b', '<i4'), ('c', 'O')]

frame
      a  b  c
0  0.0  0  0
1  0.0  0  0
2  0.0  0  0
3  0.0  0  0
4  0.0  0  0
5  0.0  0  0
6  0.0  0  0
7  0.0  0  0
8  0.0  0  0
9  0.0  0  0
frame.dtypes
 a    float64
b      int32
c     object
dtype: object
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_25.py", line 17, in <module>
    frame.loc[0, ('a', 'b', 'c')] = (1, 2, np.zeros((20, 20)))
  File "/home/bin/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 179, in __setitem__
    self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
  File "/home/bin/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 557, in _setitem_with_indexer
    elif np.array(value).ndim == 2:
Val
```

Comment: This is in general a bad idea. Pandas can't work efficiently with such structures. Try to keep scalar values in Pandas cells. You can use multiindexes, join different data frames, etc. But putting 2D arrays in Pandas cells - will ruin all Pandas beauty, efficience and power...

Comment: @MaxU I was under the impression that the underlying container is a `np.ndarray`, in case of `np.object` filled with pointers. How otherwise could I store matrices of different sizes?

Comment: I think this is kind of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/348814). In order to give you a better answer we should be able to see a bigger picture. Why do you want to store matrices of different sizes in one DF? What are you going to do with those matrices, etc.?

Comment: @MaxU. I updated the question.